# Working with Ionic3 and wikitude

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, wikitude

I have started developing an application based on AR Geolocation with ionic 3 and Wikitude plugin (cordova) and I have a problem to integrate with Ionic3.

My question is, how to integrate Wikitude with Ionic 3 ?

Comment: You could take a look at this https://github.com/Tazaf/ionicitude

Comment: thanks Alex but ionicitude dosent supported by the wikitude and dosent work with ionic 3